# AngularJS translateProvider ReferenceError when setting preferredLanguage

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm trying to make translations with AngularJS. Translations works fine while `preferredLanguage` is set to `en`. But if I change to any other for example `lt` I get error

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

on line:

```
var lcFile = require('path').join(__dirname, 'locale', lc + '.js'),
```

My app's config looks like that:

```
myApp.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {

    $translateProvider.translations('lt', {
        "OTHER_LIKES" : "{peopleCount, plural, one {# žmogus tai mėgsta} few {# žmonės tai mėgsta} other {# žmonių tai mėgsta}}",
        "YOU_AND_OTHERS_LIKES" : "{peopleCount, plural, one {tu ir # žmogus tai mėgsta} few {tu ir # žmonės tai mėgsta} other {tu ir # žmonių tai mėgsta}}",
        "YOU_LIKE" : "Tu mėgsti tai"
    });

    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        "OTHER_LIKES" : "{peopleCount, plural, one {# person likes this} few {# people likes this} other {# people likes this}}",
        "YOU_AND_OTHERS_LIKES" : "{peopleCount, plural, one {You and # other likes this} few {You and # other likes this} other {You and # other likes this}}",
        "YOU_LIKE" : "You like this"
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('lt');

    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');

    $translateProvider.addInterpolation('$translateMessageFormatInterpolation');
}]);
```

Comment: Where is the first line of code executed? From where do you get the error? What is the stack trace? It looks like you're trying to executed node.js code inside the browser.

Comment: You are right. I used wrong messageformat.js which caused the error which might have been nodeJS file

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this error in combination with [messageformat.js](https://github.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js) version 0.2.2. When setting a locale, the MessageFormat translation provider is notified. If it has not been configured with the necessary locales, it will try to `require()` the file. Since `require` is a *node.js* keyword, not supported by browsers, it fails.

To avoid this, you can e.g. concatenate the required locales from the *messageformat.js* distribution with the vendor scripts in your build process.

Example locale definition:

```
MessageFormat.locale.en=function(n){return n===1?"one":"other"}
```